# Ioinic using Jade or Pug template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pug, ionic2

In Jade/Pug:

```
ion-nav([root]="rootPage", #content, swipeBackEnabled="false")
```

Pug compiled HTML result:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content="#content" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

It should be in HTML:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

What should you think I should do to make Pug compile this right?

Comment: Are you explicitly declaring the HTML5 doctype? According to one of the later comments on [this Github issue report](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/370), the attribute was properly rendered once `doctype html` was used - maybe a similar issue?

Comment: It did yes you are right.

Comment: So that works? Because then I'd be glad to post this as a proper answer to the question, so that others can benefit from it as well :)

Comment: Yes please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the HTML5 doctype in the beginning of your template, like this: `doctype html`.

According to a comment on [this Github issue report](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/370), attributes without values are only supported in HTML5 rendering mode, meaning that the only way to have them included properly is through using the HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes on ngFor and (click) as follows:

```
button(ion-item '*ngFor'='let team of teams' '(click)'='itemTapped($event, team)')
    p {{team.name}}
```

results:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let team of teams" (click)="itemTapped($event, team)">
    <p>{{team.name}}</p>
</button>
```